# Add Else Statement

Tags: wordpress

How can I add an else statement to this code so if there are no posts, the output would be "There are currently no posts."

---

function jobs_posts_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {

```
global $post;

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'category_name' => 'jobs',
    'num'           => '5',
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'orderby'       => 'post_date',
), $atts));

$args = array(
    'category_name'  => $category_name,
    'posts_per_page' => $num,
    'order'          => $order,
    'orderby'        => $orderby,       
);

$output = '';

$posts = get_posts($args);

foreach($posts as $post) {
    
    setup_postdata($post);
    
    $output .= '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br>'.get_the_date().'<br><br>';
    
}

wp_reset_postdata();

return ''. $output .'';

}
add_shortcode('jobs_posts', 'jobs_posts_shortcode');
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check $posts are empty or not by using the PHP [empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function. check below code.

```
function jobs_posts_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {

    global $post;
    
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'category_name' => 'jobs',
        'num'           => '5',
        'order'         => 'DESC',
        'orderby'       => 'post_date',
    ), $atts ) );
    
    $args = array(
        'category_name'  => $category_name,
        'posts_per_page' => $num,
        'order'          => $order,
        'orderby'        => $orderby,       
    );
    
    $output = '';
    
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    
    if( !empty( $posts ) ){

        foreach( $posts as $post ) {
            
            setup_postdata($post);
            
            $output .= '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br>'.get_the_date().'<br><br>';
            
        }
    }else{
        $output .= __('There are currently no posts.','textdomain');
    }   
    
    wp_reset_postdata();
    
    return ''. $output .'';

}
add_shortcode( 'jobs_posts', 'jobs_posts_shortcode' );
```